# What's the relationship between energy level and position in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, linear-algebra

In my QM class, my professor is having us do a project on numerically solving the Schrödinger equation for a particle in a square well based on [this tutorial](https://liu-group.github.io/interactive-Numerov-PIB/).  I understand the tutorial fine, but one of the tasks the professor assigned (which isn't part of the linked tutorial) is to modify the tutorial's Python code so that it simulates the second energy level instead of the first and I don't understand how to do that, not because of the coding aspect but because I'm not seeing how position and energy are even related (as the plots are for psi vs position, not psi vs energy).
Like, e.g., how do you find the wavefunction for an electron at the first energy level vs the second level?  My instinct is to say we should express the Schrödinger equation in the energy Eigenbasis and then apply  boundary conditions, but can you even do that, seeing as energy is clearly one of the *dependent variables* in the position basis form?  I doubt this is what I'm expected to do anyway though, as the course hasn't yet covered how to do that sort of thing.

I know the formula to compute the different energy levels -- one of the recent HW problems we did even involved deriving the formula for the energy of a particle in a finite well.  But that formula doesn't involve position, nor does the energy level formula for an infinite well, which makes it seem like position and energy are independent of each other.  That can't be right, since in the position basis, the Schrödinger equation has energy as a dependent variable and position as an independent variable.  What am I missing here?  How do we get a useful expression relating energy and position of a particle in a box so that we can separately consider the positions of electrons at different energy levels?

I did find these two questions:

[In QM we have position and momentum space, what about energy space?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345244/in-qm-we-have-position-and-momentum-space-what-about-energy-space)

[Energy Eigenfunction Completeness](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355461/energy-eigenfunction-completeness)

and the answers to the first one say that we can express the Schrödinger equation using an energy eigenbasis, but it sounds like it's not often particularly useful to do so, nor is the actual process of how to do it clear to me.

Comment: Yes the energy eigenbasis exists and it is very important as it allows to easily compute the time evolution of the system. The relation between energy eigenstates and position eigenstates depends on the Hamiltonian.

Comment: The position eigenbasis projected on the energy eigenbasis for the harmonic oscillator  defines the [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions).